# Implementing irregularly shaped regions in a strategy game

Tags: java, libgdx, shapes, regions

I'm developing a strategy game for Android using libGDX. It's loosely based on [Risk](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risk_(game)) and requires irregularly shaped regions. However, I am having trouble deciding how to detect when a player touches a point within one of these regions.

As of now, all I have is a full map image. One idea that I've thought of is to separate the image and create individual images for each region. Then, I can arrange them like a puzzle and check if the player has touched an opaque area of one of the regions.

Comment: The thing is, irregular shaped can't really be formulated. But maybe there is a tool to do that which I am not aware of. IMHO, you already have a good idea, I think.

Comment: [Point-in-polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon) test?

Answer (score 0):

if your shaped regions are polygons defined as a set of points, you can use a algorithm to determine the point is inside or outsite like [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/84226/Is-a-Point-inside-a-Polygon).

or

i don´t lerned java, but maybe exist a control like html5 canvas hitregion.